# Sum of items not fulfilling the having by clause SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of production with columns `code`, `name`, `country`, `production`

I need to list countries that are exceeding the production of 1000 and also make a sum of production of all other countries and label it other. So the output will look like this

```
Country   production
-------   ----------
Japan     1380
England   1400
Other     2700
```

Is it possible to make this without union in one select?

Comment: Why not UNION? I wrote an alternative, but your decision should be based on query performance.

Comment: Does "ms" tag means "SQL-server" or "ms-access" please?

Comment: Is there a single row of production per country in your table or there are multiple rows?

Comment: @niktrs There are multiple rows per country. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Using a subquery:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN production >= 1000 THEN country ELSE 'Other' END country
     , SUM(production) AS production
FROM(
    SELECT country, 
           SUM(production) AS production
    FROM production
    GROUP BY country
) AS a
GROUP BY CASE WHEN production >= 1000 THEN country ELSE 'Other' END
```

Comment: Only if there is ONLY one row for production per country. Otherwise you need first to aggregate per country and then group by value

Comment: I agree specifying the uniqueness in the question would make it better.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to return all the data, but grouped differently you don't need to look at this task as a "Filtering" exercise, but only as a grouping/re-labeling exercise. To relabel everything with a production > 1000 you can use the case statement. All that is left to do is grouping. No need for any sub-queries.

```
  SELECT country = CASE WHEN production >= 1000 
                        THEN country 
                        ELSE 'Other' 
                   END 
       , production = SUM(production)
    FROM production
GROUP BY CASE WHEN production >= 1000 
              THEN country 
              ELSE 'Other' 
         END
```

If the table can contain multiple records per country, the answer of @niktrs is correct.

Comment: +1. You have a good point. The correct answer is your's if only one row exists per country.